# Flutter How to run flutter pub get while app is debugging?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a small question.

When we debug app if we press r app reloads or R hot restart.

But how to run get flutter packages.

I cannot write the whole line flutter pug get it goes to new line in command prompt.

Comment: What is your working environment?
If You are in Android Studio / Vs Code, debug the project using debug button, and do the flutter pub get from the terminal.

Comment: I want to try using command prompt

Answer (score 1):

you can use another `terminal/command prompt` go to  project directory to run `flutter pub get`.

but if you use `VsCode` it is very easy to `run` and `debug` the project
you can also use the terminal to run `flutter pub get` in it

VsCode provide `run menu` that really helps to run the project and when you save changes in `pubspec.yaml` it automatically get packages.

but make sure that you have install `flutter and dart plugins` in VsCode